# .wav vs .flac format for short game sound effects

Tags: android, audio, wav, flac

I'm upgrading about twenty .mp3 sound effect files in an android game application. The files are all about 2 seconds long so the size difference per file is about 30 KB for .wav, 22 KB for .flac, and 6 KB for .mp3. My minimum sdk is 19 (Android 4.4) so, at least according to the docs, .flac should be supported by all devices running my app despite .wav being otherwise the more supported format.

Both are supposed to be lossless, although .flac is compressed, so you have decompression time. I expect that would be near undetectable though in this case. Since my production APK is about 23 MB, I'm not that concerned with the 160 KB or so I'd save using .flac vs .wav, and for this reason I'm thinking of just going with what I expect is the more 'base' .wav format.

Which would be the better default format for short audio clips?

Comment: `Which would be the better default format for short audio clips?` is very opinion based, you seem to know the differences between the formats, and which is more compatible, so in some ways you've answered your own question.  If you're not worried about space then .wav is the obvious choice as it more widely compatible and there's no decompression required